# Grails run app failed because of dependencies xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1

Tags: java, maven, grails

I'm trying to compile a project in grails 2.5.0. When I run `grails run-app` I'm getting this following error:

```
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1 from/to mavenCentral (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Range Not Satisfiable (416) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1 from/to mavenCentral (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Range Not Satisfiable (416) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1 from/to mavenCentral (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Range Not Satisfiable (416) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Could not transfer artifact xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1 from/to mavenCentral (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Range Not Satisfiable (416)
| Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

Running with --stacktrace:

```
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1 from/to mavenCentral (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Range Not Satisfiable (416) (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1 from/to mavenCentral (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Range Not Satisfiable (416)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy:514)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultTestDependencies_closure16.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy:588)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultTestDependencies_closure16.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getDefaultTestDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:582)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getTestDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:563)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1 from/to mavenCentral (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Range Not Satisfiable (416)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1 from/to mavenCentral (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Range Not Satisfiable (416)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Range Not Satisfiable (416)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.handleStatus(HttpTransporter.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9935 -- Here I found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. Just delete the cache files ~/.m2/repositories and it run properly.